# Pronunciation of "lib"

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I've been a computer programmer for many years, and recently my father has been learning computer programming. Programmers often times will use a folder called "lib."

Not a native English speaker, my father pronounced "lib" like *lib*eria - short for "library."

When I corrected him and told him it's pronounced "lib" like *li*t, he asked why if "lib" is supposed to be short for "library."

I couldn't think of an answer why. I thought of other words such as

- "pup", short for "puppy" is pronounced like the first part of puppy
- "mic", short for "microphone" is pronounced like the first part of microphone

Why is "lib" not pronounced like the first part of library?

Comment: For the same reason it's *fidelity* but *hi-fi*. (^_^)

Comment: Who else says it isn't?  I pronounce "char" the same as the beginning of "character" when it is supposed to mean "character".

Comment: I'm guilty of pronouncing lib and `char` phonetically. But GEdgar has a point: Who says it's _not_ pronounced as it is in "library"?

Comment: The pronunciation probably comes from *ad-lib* people have become used to pronouncing that with a hard b as in nib. The lib from library merely followed that, rather than a shortened form of library with a soft b as in libation.

Comment: I must say, as an  engineer and programmer for 50 years, I have always pronounced "lib" (in the programming sense) the same as the beginning of "library".  I've known a few people who pronounced it the same as the beginning of "liberty", but they were in the minority (or were simply being "cute").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pronunciations of shortened forms and derived forms don't depend on those of originals. For instance, *pronunciation ~ pronounce, professor ~ prof, library ~ lib, microphone ~ mic*.

Trisyllabic laxing and precluster shortening should have shortened the first vowel in *library*; but it has not happened. That has to do with these: trisyllabic laxing does not apply to non-derived forms (Kiparsky's explanation); precluster shortening treats clusters like pr, br, etc as a single consonant. That's why we have historically long vowels in *apron, April, acre* (vs. *Akron*, OH), *libra*, *maple* (vs. *apple*). In the latter set, you can see ME open syllable lengthening as well.

Answer (score 4):

When there is a conflict between how you would expect an abbreviation to be pronounced judging from its spelling alone, and how you would expect judging from the sounds of the larger word, then it can go either way. Or in another direction entirely.

If we considered such abbreviations to be words in their own right then we wouldn't be surprised at this. Related words aren't always pronounced in matching ways, after all. Some also are pronounced in matching ways in some dialects and accents, and not in others.

The only real difference, is that if we are still thinking of it as an abbreviation (unlike say *laser* which most of us think of as fully a word rather than an initialism or *amphetamine* which most of us think of as fully a word rather than as an abbreviation for *alphamethyl-phenethylamine*), then they are probably quite recent.

Further, abbreviations can be coined in text quite separate from speech (people will still write *etc* and yet pronounce it *et cetera* and that's a very old one), or coined in speech quite separate from text (people form shortened forms of anything they regularly talk about, but often would still use the full form in writing). This in itself will have an effect on whether seeing *lib* will make you think /laɪˈb/ or /lɪb/.

There's also in this case the fact that we have several other abbreviations spelled *lib*. We've the long-standing *ad lib* for *ad libitum*, *lib* for *Liberal* (the name or part of the name of several political parties around the world), *lib* for *liberation* (as in "Woman's Lib", "Gay Lib" though that term has fallen out of favour, make of the lack of interest in liberation, what you will).

Of those matching the pronunciation of *library*, we've only a half-point, since *Libra* is sometimes pronounced /ˈlaɪbrə/ and sometimes /ˈlibrə/. (I've personally only encountered that as text-only abbreviations, pronounced as if they was written in full, and anyway).

So with so many cases of *lib* already pronounced /lɪb/, the odds where in the favour of that becoming the pronunciation used.

At least as far as I've heard. I've also found that abbreviations are more likely than other words to produce not only claiming that they pronounce it differently, but insisting quite strongly that they've only ever heard it that way in their lives.

Answer (score 4):

We call it a /*lib*/ folder for the same reason we call the "/etc" folder /*et see*/ and not "et cetera". Or the same reason we pronounce "var" as /*vahr*/ not /*vaer*/ or "bin" as /*bin*/ and not /*bine*/ and proc is not /*pross*/.

First, it's easier to say, but more importantly, these abbreviations are no longer abbreviations.  They have become words on their own right.  "/lib" no longer really stands for "library", it means "lib".  No one refers to an ".exe" file as an "*exeh*" (-cutable) and ".co.uk" is pronounced with a long O.  You generally pronounce neologisms how they're spelled, not by what they mean.

A nontechnical example is the word bus.  "Bus" is short for omnibus (accent on the NI).  If we were to pronounce it as an abbreviation, we'd call it a /*bis*/, but it's it's own word - a /*bus*/.

Comment: Please excuse the fake IPA.  I don't have the concentration right now to figure it out, but anyone's welcome to fix my mistakes.

Comment: I've certainly heard the /etc folder pronounced the same way as *etc* normally is - expanded to *et cetera*. I don't recall ever hearing it pronounced as "et C", though I may just have not realised they were talking about the /etc folder. (Always mistrust "I have never heard").

Comment: Note that this idea that you should pronounce abbreviations as they are spelled ***only*** works in technical computer-speak. I've only heard *veg* and *Reg* pronounced to rhyme with *ledge* and not *beg*. And *synch* rhymes with *zinc,* not *pinch*.

Comment: The person who named "etsy" said it came from the Italian "et si" ("Oh yes") which would also mean "and if" in Latin, but was primarily chosen because he wanted a meaningless word (meaningless in English) and he was watching a Fellini film where someone kept saying "oh, yes" which to an English-speaker is this meaningless phrase "etsy, etsy" being repeated.

Comment: @PeterShor That's an interesting point.  If it's true, I wonder why that is.  My guess is that it's the difference between a language that's mostly spoken (English) and a language that's mostly written (tech-speak).

Comment: @JonHanna Then I assumed incorrectly.  Withdrawn.

Comment: @JonHanna Btw, it looks like it's not so simple about the origin of Etsy's name: https://www.quora.com/How-did-Etsy-get-its-name  Basically, the founders have agreed to lie. See also http://www.thenameinspector.com/etsy/